# I would like to remove trailing zeros from excel. But when i try to use substitute function i get function not defined error

Tags: excel, vba

If i use Trim with Replace function as `MyCell.Value = Trim(Replace(MyCell.Value, Chr(160), Chr(32)))` it removes my leading zeros.

```
Sub TrimText()
    Dim MyCell As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Selection.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select
        For Each MyCell In Selection.Cells
            MyCell.Value = TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(G7, CHAR(160), " "))
        Next
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: `MyCell.Value` wants a value, not a formula (and your formula is not quoted)

Comment: Are your leading zeroes fixed?

Comment: Is the number of digits (with one or more leading zeroes) fixed after you remove leading and trailing spaces?

Comment: As i have formatted to text, my leading zeros are maintained as expected. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub TrimText()
    Dim MyCell As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Selection.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select
        For Each MyCell In Selection.Cells
            'Range("K:K").Select
            Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
            MyCell.Value = Trim(Replace(MyCell.Value, Chr(160), Chr(32)))
        Next
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: I formatted your code block but I'm curious what the `Range("K:K").Select` is intended to do and why the number format on an entire column is repeated within the loop. It seems once should be enough. A sentence or two in the way of explaining what you are offering as a solution goes a long way to creating a quality post.

Comment: Hey sorry i have removed it as i have used it as reference to test.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is not the `Substitute` function but the `CHAR`. Use `Chr` instead.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, also Substitute is wrong. Write `WorksheetFunction.Substitute(...)`.

`SUBSTITUTE` and `CHAR` just work as Excel functions but not as VBA functions in the way you use them.

Comment: I changed using Chr but it still shows me 'Function not defined' :(

Comment: I tried this too now the whole value is getting erased. Is there any other way to remove trailing spaces without removing the leading zeros in macro. I have no idea as i'm new to Macro

Comment: What is your final goal? Remove zeros or spaces, trailing or leading?

Comment: Remove the space at the end of each field without removing the leading zeros

Comment: Why not just `MyCell.Value = RTrim(MyCell.Value)` or even shorter `MyCell = RTrim(MyCell)`

Comment: Thanks a lot Fratyx.. I was not able to use Rtrim bcs that didn't resolve the issue, the trailing spaces were still there..    But i have found some code and made alterations and it worked..