# VBA : Most efficient way to not display trailing zeros in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, format

After seeing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27243676/i-would-like-to-remove-trailing-zeros-from-excel-but-when-i-try-to-use-substitu) I was wondering what's the best way to remove trailing zeros in a cell with VBA when value is stored in a cell as string. By `the best way` I mean the shortest line of code and the fastest way (both criteria matters in this Q&A).

I tried this which works but not efficient enough to my eyes :
`Sheet_Nomenclature.Cells(i, 10) = Trim(Sheet_Nomenclature.Cells(i, 10) / 10) * 10`

**EDIT :**
Thanks to the comments i'll bring some precisions on some points that can create misunderstanding.

When I say `remove trailing zeros` it's incorrect I meant `not display the trailing zeros` that's why this solution works.

Also the goal was this :
`23,450 -> 23,45` Or `23,000 -> 23`

Hope this is clearer to everyone.

Comment: What do you mean specifically by "remove"? Not display? If so, change the cell's `.NumberFormat`.

Comment: Are these values actually strings (with cells formatted as text) or numbers? If it's numbers, use `.NumberFormat`; if it's a string, use a textual replace. Or, as @etienne does, make it a number (but first make sure the cell is not formatted as text).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's the most accurate answer I've found by myself :
`Sheet1.Cells(i, 8) = CDbl(Sheet1.Cells(i, 8))`

**Note :** This Q&A is talking about trailing zeros (zeros behind the value) only. I hope that I'm understandable was my first Q&A on SA.

Comment: What do you mean by "zeros behind the value"? It should be good to show us, at least, an example. Do you mean something as `002345.234`? If so, was it only formatted in this way, or it's a string? Looking to the solution you 'found', it probably was a string/text. If so, you should state it...

Comment: What your code does it converts a string into a number. That's not "removing zeros*, that's converting it into a complete different data type. A **string** can have any character you want (it can also look like a number). A **number** never has any leading or trailing zero.

Comment: And the solution will not work in case the cell was formatted beforhand having  "trailing" zeros. DV

Comment: @Storax yes that's why I said that is this Q&A I do a particular cases...

Comment: What is the particular case? There is nothing in the post about a special case! If I format a  cell to display trailing zeros that number format will not be removed by your code. So 23,000 will not change to 23!

Comment: @Storax for a more global case just force format like this ```cell.NumberFormat = "0.######"``` but often in vba value manipulation outside of the code are going through cells or strings/arrays so that's why I thought my solution was pretty generic at first. Nevertheless thanks for your indications :)